# Vue.js changing data and re-rendering timing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, plotly, plotly.js

I'm new to Vue.js.

I would like to change data in methods, and change the view according to the data.

```
// template
<div v-if="currentGraphType.type === 'foo'">
  <!-- Some other graphs -->
</div>
<div v-else id="plotly-graph" />

// methods
onClickGraphType(graphType: { type: string, name: string }) {
  this.currentGraphType = graphType;
  this.renderGraph();
},
```

`renderGraph()` renders svg elements in `div#plotly-graph`

But when `onClickGraphType` is executed and changes the `currentGraphType` to 'foo' , the graph is not rendered.

I think `<div v-else id="plotly-graph" />` is somehow not rendered before `this.renderGraph()` is executed.

Do I misunderstand how Vue.js data works?

Comment: Did you mean to have an id only on the else condition?

Comment: Yes. I wanna use the elements rendered by `this.renderGraph()` only when `currentGraphType.type !== 'foo'` .

Comment: Why don't you just do `<div v-if="currentGraphType.type !== 'foo'" id="plotly-graph"></div>`? When you use `v-if` and `v-else`, there is only one div rendered at any time.

Comment: I want the `div#plotly-graph` only when `currentGraphType.type !== 'foo'` .

Comment: In your question, you say it's not rendering when you set currentGraphType to 'foo'.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: When currentGraphType is 'foo', I want to render other elements in `<div v-if="currentGraphType.type === 'foo'">`  and not `<div v-else id="plotly-graph" />`. I edited the code in question.

Comment: Can we see your data definition?

Comment: `{ currentGraphType: {} }` . graphType is object like `{ type: string, name: string }` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, you're calling `this.renderGraph()` synchronously before Vue can update the DOM.

Try to defer `this.renderGraph()` with `$nextTick()`:

```
onClickGraphType(graphType: { type: string, name: string }) {
  this.currentGraphType = graphType;
  this.$nextTick(() => this.renderGraph());
},
```

Comment: Sorry, `graphType` is object like { type: 'some_type', ... }. I'll edit the question.